# equals() method?

Tags: java

shouldn´t one pass an object to equal?

```
    String hej = pets.getBark();
    if(hej.equals("woff"))
```

why are you able to pass a string woff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, a string literal ( text inside quotes ) automatically is replaced by String instance. ( a string literal is shorthand for `new String` )

That is why this code works: `String hello = "hello";`

So,

```
 String hej = pets.getBark();
 if( hej.equals( new String("woff") ) ) {}
```

is identical to the code you provided.

Comment: It's actually not exactly the same as that, due to string interning, IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question properly you are wondering why a literal string value can be passed to a method that accepts an argument of type `String`.  This is because a string literal is a shorthand for a [`String`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instance (either a new instance or a previously created instance that has been preserved by means of interning):

> The `String` class represents character
>   strings. ***All string literals in Java
>   programs, such as "abc", are
>   implemented as instances of this
>   class.***

Answer (score 2):

A quoted string is an object.  It is an instance of the String class.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `java.lang.String`, a subtype of `java.lang.Object`, because [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says so.

Answer (score 1):

A literal string is still of type String.